# detecting window event

Tags: java

Can someone tell me what's wrong in the below code,  I am getting syntax error in the first line.

```
    WindowEvent winClosingEvent = new WindowEvent(this,WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(winClosingEvent);
```

Thanks

Comment: Always best if you show us the actual error message itself rather than make us guess.

Comment: Also, what type of class is `this`? Is it derived from Window?

Comment: What is the exact error message? We also need more code. See http://www.sscce.org for suggestions on what code you can post to help get the answer you want more quickly.

Comment: No suitable constructor found for WindowEvent - this is the error message.  I have a JFrame in a class it has a JCombobox, when the user selects a particular option, another window opens, I wanted to close the previous window when the new window opens.

Comment: If you were going to close a Window, this is not how you'd do it, instead you'd simply call `dispose()` on the first window. But more importantly, I think that a better solution is to use a better design. How many programs do you run that shows a bunch of windows swapping? Why not instead swap *views* using a CardLayout.

Comment: dispose is also working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of two possible issues is occurring here.

1) You haven't imported `java.awt.event.WindowEvent` and therefore the class cannot be found by the compiler.

2) Your `this` reference does not point to an instance of `java.awt.Window`.